# Headers are invisible after sending HTTP request

Tags: http, header, request, telnet, invisible

After I send an HTTP request using `telnet www.example.com 80`, the headers I type in are invisible; they work, but I just can't see what I am typing in and if I am making any typos. How can I make the headers visible?

Comment: Do you have to use telnet? What's wrong with curl?

Comment: Or, if you must use telnet, prepare your input in a text file and pipe/paste from there into telnet.

Comment: I'm following an online lesson, that's why I'm using telnet. Do you know what is causing the text to be invisible?